# Geodesics in norm balls

Tags: complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesics

Recently, some problems that I work on require that I understand a bit of hyperbolic complex geometry. Assume that $B \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is the unit ball of some norm $\|\cdot\|$ (not induced by an inner product). Main example for me are Cartan domains of type I. Assume that I am given a point $p \in B$, such that $p/\|p\|$ is not a complex extreme point. I would like to parametrize the complex geodesics, that connect the origin to $p$. I looked at some literature, but couldn't find anything definitive, besides the fact that they are not unique.Is such a parametrization possible in the generality that I've formulated it in? Is it possible for Cartan domains?